# My images are not displaying in the front-end of my site, but it is in the backend

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a backend to an automotive company. This is so that they can manage their vehicle stock and display "for sale+ items on their website.

The backend resides on the same server as the website in a sub-directory.

In this sub-directory I have a folder where the uploaded images are stored from a form in the backend. This all works 100%. The entire backend works like it's supposed to.

Here's the problem, as soon as I loop through the DB to view the images on the website, it doesn't display. All the other data from the DB displays just fine, but not the images.

Here's my code.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dbName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection to database failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>




<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['make']; ?> <?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php

                            $dir="http://myurl/uploaded_images/";

                        $filePath = $row['images_path'];
                        $fileArray = explode("*", $filePath);

                        foreach ($fileArray as $file) {
                            if (file_exists($dir.$file)) {
                                echo "<img src='$dir/$file'>";
                            }
                        }

                        echo $row['images_path'];

                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php

    }
}
?>
```

I thinks it's worth noting that the front-end is Joomla. I'm using a plugin called Sourcerer to include the PHP code in side an article.

Comment: Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - you have syntax errors.

Comment: replace `/` with `dot`  `<img src='$dir.$file'>`

Comment: your file_exist check $dir.$file and your <img src="$dir/$file"> both are different please correct it as Saty says

Comment: I hope that those aren't your actual database credentials. If they are I'd suggest masking them in your comment and changing them on the server immediately.

Comment: joomla is not a "front-end" either

Comment: Deon, give me a second to check your database so I can be more of help.

Comment: @Adelphia "idiot left his db credentials" :D :D :D

Comment: Also, Deon, md5 is a bit deprecated, there are a lot of websites which have huge precomputed md5 decrypters. And I guess admin is not the best password. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

replace your similar code with this

```
foreach ($fileArray as $file) {
    if (file_exists($dir.$file)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$dir.$file.'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you get a example of $row['images_path'] ?